# Why my function does not showing file extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation

I'm trying to make a function for validate the file during uploading using javascript, i have done it, all is well and working properly but it does not showing extension in alert (I want to show file extension is alert), can any one let me know where the problem? I have successfully validate the size now i want to validate the extension.

### Javascript

```
function showFileSize() {
 var rt = true;
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        bodyAppend("p", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
        rt = false;
    }

   inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

   for(var ind=0;ind<inputs.length;ind++){
        var sFileName = inputs.item(ind).files[0].name;
        var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
     if(inputs.item(ind).type=='file'){
        if(!inputs.item(ind).files[0]){
         alert("Please select  file "+(ind+1)+" before clicking 'Load'");
         rt = false;
         }else if(inputs.item(ind).files[0].size>6000000){
            console.log(inputs.item(ind).files[0].size);
            alert("File size should be less then 6MB!"+sFileExtension);
            rt = false;
            }

        }  
   }
//If Function True 
if(rt == true){
     doForm(
            '{var name=form_controller}', 
            'manageForm',
            '1',
            0, 
            0, 
            1);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check `sFileName` for the expected value (e.g. `alert(sFileName);`).

Then change the extension split to:

```
var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code into this:

```
var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.');
console.log(sFileExtension); //make sure it generates the right array
sFileExtension = sFileExtension[sFileExtension.length - 1].toLowerCase();
alert(sFileExtension);
```

Another way to get the last element of an Array you can use [.pop()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp), like this

```
var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
alert(sFileExtension);
```